# jquery - Calculate the sum and total of products

Tags: jquery

I have a set of products with Qty, price and Sum in each line like in this picture:

[image]

I want to make it with jquery to auto calculate the Sum in each line and the total in the end, without quitting the page.

I don't have a big experience with jquery.

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post your markup so we can see how that table is formed? It will be difficult to give an appropriate answer otherwise, other than something like "Get the quantity, multiply it by the price, repeat for all rows, adding total as you go".

Comment: Need more information, can you post the HTML?

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for reply, I want to add that jqury function to Magento grouped products, like in this page : 

http://demo.magentocommerce.com/magento-red-furniture-set.html

in this demo website, there is not a sum value per line, I have to add it...

I hope that I was clear, thanks for help :=

Comment: ill try to make a fiddle off what we have...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/2/  I think this is what you may want :) alex did most of the work but hey :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/

Comment: The "Quantity" have to be an aditable input text field

Comment: Alex i'd put your code on here aswell if I was you, as jsfiddle uses tempo-links :) and someone would get lost in the future when the link doesn't work, or show some unrelated contents :)

Comment: Or, for a little bit more of a complex example with number formatting: http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/Tnj7u/1/

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fiddle of what i think you want to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qEy3L/

JS:

```
function getTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.price').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
}

getTotal();
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>SUM</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1.25</td>
            <td class='price'>2.50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2.10</td>
            <td class='price'>6.30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>10.50</td>
            <td class='price'>52.50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Total</td>
            <td id='total'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Here is a version with an updatable QTY: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qEy3L/5/

JS:

```
function getTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.sum').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
}

getTotal();

$('.qty').keyup(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var price = $('.price', parent);
    var sum = $('.sum', parent);
    var value = parseInt(this.value) * parseFloat(price.get(0).innerHTML||0);
    sum.text(value);
    getTotal();
})
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>SUM</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class='qty' size='1'/></td>
            <td class='price'>1.25</td>
            <td class='sum'>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class='qty' size='1'/></td>
            <td class='price'>2.10</td>
            <td class='sum'>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class='qty' size='1'/></td>
            <td class='price'>10.50</td>
            <td class='sum'>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Total</td>
            <td id='total'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: he wants to calculate the price aswell :)

Comment: when value is null, then u get NaN so price should be parsed properly :)

Comment: @Neal your `||0` at the end of the row calculation is very cool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your comman is meant to be a decimal point(from French numbering system)
The one below should work with tables aswell and so on.

```
<ul class="row">
  <li class="qty">2</li>
  <li class="price">2.45</li>
  <li class="sum"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="qty">3</li>
  <li class="price">24.5</li>
  <li class="sum"></li>
</ul>
<div id="total"></div>


//jquery
$('.row').each(function(i,n){
   var sum = ( parseFloat($(n).children('.qty')) * parseFloat($(n).children('.price')) );
   $(n).children('.sum').text(sum)
}).delay(1).queue(function(){
   var total = 0;
   $('.sum').each(function(i,n){
      total += parseFloat($(n).text());
   });
   $('#total').text(total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but I found Neal's answer very helpful and made a spin-off that I think can be helpful in various situations.

This version allows inputs for both quantity and price, and also allows rows to be dynamically added to the table and still function properly. I also added rounding into the mix since I figure that this is most likely a monetary calculation (just remove all instances of `.toFixed(2)` if not needed).

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#order-entry").on("keyup", ".form-calc", function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
        parent.find(".form-line").val((parent.find(".form-qty").val() * parent.find(".form-cost").val()).toFixed(2));
        var total = 0;
        $(".form-line").each(function(){
            total += parseFloat($(this).val()||0);
        });
        $("#total").text(total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="order-entry">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Sum</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="form-calc form-qty" value="1"></td>
            <td><input class="form-calc form-cost" value="10.00"></td>
            <td><input class="form-line" value="0" readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="form-calc form-qty" value="2"></td>
            <td><input class="form-calc form-cost" value="5.33"></td>
            <td><input class="form-line" value="0" readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total</td>
            <td id="total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```